# How do I set the slotMinutes different than the drag interval?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I set slot minutes to 5, then it shows time intervals of 5 minutes on the left.

I want it to show time intervals of 30 minutes, but allow dragging to intervals of 5 minutes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=495
(not yet implemented, but some clues on that issue)